Feasibility of methods for nodal analysis of a complex RC circuit network
<Circuit 1>

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I need to perform nodal analysis on the <Circuit 1> and much larger lattice RC circuits. The resistance and capacitance are randomly distributed. All capacitors are initially discharged. My ultimate goal is to express the potential drop (and current) across each resistor/capacitor with respect to time. Since the inherent purpose of my research is network analysis, a circuit network may require a graphical representation (with nodes and edges), and this makes nodal analysis favorable to other methods like loop analysis. The potential drop is difference between two adjacent labeled nodes, and the solution can be obtained either analytically or numerically. In <Circuit 1>, the lattice RC component is connected to 2 busbars at the top and bottom.
Before solving <Circuit 1>, I've created a different, simpler circuit, <Circuit 2>. I want to find the method that work and is also scalable for different size of the RC circuit network.The resistance and capacitance are randomly distributed. All capacitors are initially discharged. \$ v_a\$ and \$v_e\$ are the supernode and reference/ground node, respectively. Down below, I've summarized what I've done so far to solve this (all failure).
OBJECTIVE: find the nodal voltages \$v_b (t), v_c (t), v_d (t)\$
<Circuit 2>

simulate this circuit
1. Nodal admittance matrix, frequency domain, and inverse Laplace transform Other examples
\$ E(t) = V_0 u(t) \rightarrow E(s) = \frac{V_0}{s} \$ where \$ s = \sigma+ j\omega = \sigma \$ and in general, \$ Y_C = sC\$ and \$ Y_R = G\$. Below is the \$ \mathbf{Y}_{\text{MNA}}\mathbf{V}_{\text{MNA}}=\mathbf{I}_{\text{MNA}}\$, a transformed matrix equation of \$ \mathbf{Y}\mathbf{V}=\mathbf{I}\$ by substituting conditions of the supernode and ground. (\$ \mathbf{Y}\$ is a Laplacian matrix.)
\begin{gather}
 \begin{bmatrix}
   sC_1 & - sC_1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
   - sC_1 & sC_1 + G_1 & - G_1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & - G_1 & sC_2 + G_1 & - sC_2 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & - sC_2 & sC_2 + G_2 & 0 \\
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
 \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
   v_a \\
   v_b \\
   v_c \\
   v_d \\
   i_{V_0}
 \end{bmatrix}
 =
 \begin{bmatrix}
   0 \\
   0 \\
   0 \\
   0 \\
   \frac{V_0}{s}
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{gather}
Given \$C\$, \$G\$, and \$V_0\$, only \$s\$ is left as a variable, required for the inverse Laplace transform (and obtaining the nodal voltage expressions in time). This becomes a huge problem: I must compute the inverse of \$ \mathbf{Y}_{\text{MNA}}\$ symbolically. Below image is \$\mathbf{Y}_{\text{MNA}}^{-1}\$ obtained using Sympy. Additionally, I must perform the inverse Laplace transform symbolically; both operations are very costly in time. It is evident that this method is unfeasible specifically my problem unless I magically find some pattern in the inverse matrix or the solution vector.

2. Matrix differential equation 1: construction of the matrix from the standard modified nodal analysis Example
\begin{gather}
 \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
   0 & G_1 & - G_1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & - G_1 & G_1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & G_2 & 0 \\
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
 \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
   v_a \\
   v_b \\
   v_c \\
   v_d \\
   i_{V_0}
 \end{bmatrix}
+
 \begin{bmatrix}
   C_1 & - C_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   - C_1 & C_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & C_2 & - C_2 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & - C_2 & C_2 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
 \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
   \dot{v}_a \\
   \dot{v}_b \\
   \dot{v}_c \\
   \dot{v}_d \\
   \dot{i}_{V_0}
 \end{bmatrix}
 =
 \begin{bmatrix}
   0 \\
   0 \\
   0 \\
   0 \\
   V_0
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{gather}
\$ \mathbf{G}\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{C}\mathbf{\dot{x}} = \mathbf{b} \$. \$\mathbf{C}\$ and \$\mathbf{G}\$ will always be singular for my problem (the pattern is that the 3x3 submatrix in the middle gives 0 determinant). Additionally, pseudo inverse of \$\mathbf{C}\$ results in the last row full of zeros, which also messes up with computing numerical solution.
3. Matrix differential equation 2: construction of reduced matrix
\begin{gather}
 \begin{bmatrix}
   - G_1 & G_1 & 0 \\
   G_1 & - G_1 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & - G_2
 \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
   v_b \\
   v_c \\
   v_d
 \end{bmatrix}
+
 \begin{bmatrix}
   C_1 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & C_2 & - C_2\\
   0 & - C_2 & C_2
 \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
   \dot{v}_b \\
   \dot{v}_c \\
   \dot{v}_d
 \end{bmatrix}
 =
 \begin{bmatrix}
   0 \\
   0 \\
   0
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{gather}
To my understanding, this matrix equation is basically a reduced form of the previous one using the fact that \$ \frac{d}{dt} v_a (t) = 0 \enspace \forall t\$. The same problem persists.
Personal comment
I'm just an undergraduate student, I'm so exhausted, I'd really appreciate your expert advice and help. I wish I was better at circuit analysis, but I've really given all so far. I have transformed from someone who hates circuit and barely passed DC circuit course to solving AC circuit problems day and night. Since circuit simulators like Falstad or PySpice use modified nodal voltage and perform circuit analysis flawlessly, I must be doing something wrong. I would greatly appreciate specific advice. I'm kind of running out of time as I've been stuck on this same problem for the past three weeks straight.

fusedxbrain - Hi, Stack Exchange works best when there is a single, clear, reasonably-scoped question, which is described with enough detail that an answer is possible within a few paragraphs. || I saw that the question asked for "specific advice" but I didn't see a clear question. Please can you [edit] the question to make it clearer what you are asking (preferably just in one sentence) and to help even more, explain what you hope to get as an answer (I'm not saying that's what you will receive, but it helps readers to understand your expectation). TY

I concur (with Sam) that I don't know what OP's objective is. Is he trying to learn about circuit analysis? Is he working toward writing his own general-purpose circuit simulator? Or what?  I will say that I have been doing circuit analysis for a very long time, and never heard about modified nodal analysis. Looking up what this is, it appears to be a way to make simple problems (that can easily be solved by nodal analysis) into more complex problems. In nodal analysis a compact system matrix can be written by inspection.

I do understand the confusion. Basically, modified nodal analysis involves a solvable matrix equation by taking the supernode and reference condition and current from source into account. I want to know how to algorithmically obtain the $v_b (t), v_c (t),v_d (t)$ either numerically or analytically. The first circuit is the ultimate goal for applying nodal analysis for now. I've edited my post to make it more clear.

@Fred, modified nodal analysis (MNA) is just nodal analysis with supernodes to handle voltage sources. If you ever thought you did nodal analysis on a circuit with a voltage source, you likely did MNA instead. Every time you ever used SPICE to solve a circuit, you used MNA.

@ThePhoton Sorry I had to make it clear that these two circuits are different, and circuit 2 is like a "toy problem" to test methods before applying to the circuit 2.

Is the arrow down from Va to the negative source terminal meant to represent a wire or just a place where potential is measured? Also for MNA you must designate a reference node relative to which all other potentials will be measured. (and for which there will be no node equation)

The arrow represents current $ I_{V_0}$ from node $v_a$ to the positive source terminal. Thank you for spotting the error, when I edited the circuit to make it horizontal I made a mistake. The small dot at the end of the arrowhead means nothing but seems to be unremovable. The reference node is $v_e$, hence all matrices have no equations/rows relating to the KCL equation at $ v_e $.


Since circuit simulators like Falstad or PySpice use modified nodal voltage and perform circuit analysis flawlessly, I must be doing something wrong.

SPICE simulators solve these problems numerically, not symbolically.
If you're trying to reproduce what SPICE does, just solve the matrix numerically.
If you need a symbolic solution for some reason, that's a different problem from what SPICE does, and you shouldn't expect it to be easy just because SPICE can solve these circuits numerically.
In fact as the number of elements in the circuit increases you should expect the symbolic solution to become very complicated very quickly. This will make the solution more or less indecipherable to the human mind, and therefore brings into question the usefulness of having a symbolic solution.

I'm very sorry, I'm aware these two circuits are different. I just edited the wording from "To solve <circuit 2>" to "Before solving <circuit 1>. Also I need solution "either numerically or analytically." I'm just looking for any feasible solution that works and if anyone has a clue on this....

The reference node is $ v_e $, hence all matrices have no equations/rows relating to the KCL equation at $v_e $. Just like other MNA (I'm not sure if there's any formalism but), both the supernode condition ($v_a = V_0 $) and source current moving to the LHS of the KCL equation at $v_a$ (or the first row) have been taken in to the account to yield the matrix of MNA.

@fusedxbrain Generalizing from what you've shown, it seems like there is a lot of symmetry to be used to advantage.

The symbolic analysis of an electrical network of any size is feasible if you can access a main frame. The analysis with a personal computer is subject to the size of the network so it is not always feasible. In the case in question with my personal computer I obtain a "TABLEAU" matrix with dimensions (30 x 30) and the symbolic calculation of voltages and currents is very slow inexplicably, while in sinusoidal regime the calculation is very fast even for much larger matrices, so I give up, however I publish the entire procedure in the following image (I add that from the previously created matrices, one could obtain the MNA matrix, so the dimensions are greatly reduced and the solution is easily reached.):

Although the second circuit is simple and solvable by inspection, I consider the analysis obtained from the network topology and the use of the tableau matrix as in the first case as can be seen in the following photo:


This is a fantastic answer. I used MathCad in the early 90s for high school assignments, and this looks just like it looked back then. Good memories :)

The analysis in sinusoidal regime is very fast, I attach the results:

